continuity of a function defined in a compact metric space
Let $K$ be a compact metric space and $S\subset K$ a compact subspace such that
$$S \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{s_i}$$
where each $s_i \in S$ and $B_{s_i}$ are open balls centered at $s_i$
consider de function
$$\psi_j(t)=\frac{\text{dist}(t,B_{s_j}^c)}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\text{dist}(t,B_{s_i}^c)},\,\,\,\,t\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{s_i}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\psi_j(t)=0,\,\,\,\,\,t \in K-\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} B_{s_i}\right) $$
How to show that the functions $\psi_j$ are continuous??
context for the problem: In my class I'm studying Ekeland variational principle, and the proof of a general minimax theorem is dependent of the obove fact. I asked my professor about the continuity of this functions, and he said that it follows by Urysohn Lemma, but I simply don't understand how. Clearly that function is continuous inside the union and in the interior of the complementar of the union, but, how to prove continuity in the boundary?

Does this answer your question? Tietze extension theorem in LCH spaces
